# Can not connect to wordpress in localhost (GET http://localhost/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)

Tags: php, wordpress

I just backup wordpress DB and public_html folder in virtual-web-hosting.

And I move them to my local MAMP.

But when I enter http://localhost:8888/, it just transfer to http://localhost.

And the error message `(GET http://localhost/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)` shows in chrome.

Could some one give me some hint?

I had tried to put a dummy index.php with echo "debug" in /htdoc/test

and then connected to http://localhost:8888/test, it shows "debug" just as expected.

Thanks.

Comment: `get http://localhost` implies you're running a proxy, and telling the proxy to fetch an "external" url. a normal non-proxied http request would be `GET /`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change the site url and home url on your Wordpress database.

On your phpMyAdmin (should be http://localhost/phpmyadmin)

Go to your options table, search the option_value for your previous site url and change to localhost (e.g. www.domain.com to localhost)

Its best to run of port 80 though instead of 8888.

Comment: Great that worked, however if your using the site on localhost as suppose to the domain (if you were using it on one before) you will need to update those two fields, but if you been on localhost the whole time then this is of course irrelevant.

Comment: If you change only the port you won't be able to access to the admin part. So you need to change your site_url in wp_options as well.

Comment: Changing port `8888` to `80` solved it for me on MAMP PRO 4.